# couldnot get access token for daemon applications office 365

Tags: rest, go, office365

I have followed the blog http://blogs.msdn.com/b/exchangedev/archive/2015/01/22/building-demon-or-service-apps-with-office-365-mail-calendar-and-contacts-apis-oauth2-client-credential-flow.aspx to create a daemon application . I am able to get the app only token for the domain in which i have registered the application . But when I try to get for other organizations it throws an error 
"

```
{"error":"invalid_client","error_description":"AADSTS70002: Error validating cre
dentials. AADSTS50012: Client assertion audience claim does not match Realm issu
er.\r\nTrace ID: 09e025f5-7db9-46c3-9df9-574c6820a011\r\nCorrelation ID: f4d0fa5
7-ee8c-4443-b28b-d372d945f81f\r\nTimestamp: 2015-05-04 13:51:51Z","error_codes":
[70002,50012],"timestamp":"2015-05-04 13:51:51Z","trace_id":"09e025f5-7db9-46c3-
9df9-574c6820a011","correlation_id":"f4d0fa57-ee8c-4443-b28b-d372d945f81f","subm
it_url":null,"context":null}"
```

But i have configured the application to be multi tenant .

this is the request i make

```
request https://login.windows.net/<tenantId>/oauth2/to
ken
grant_type=client_credentials
redirect_uri=http://localhost.com:9000
resource=https://outlook.office365.com/
client_assertion_type =urn:ietf:params:oauth:client-assertion-type:jwt-bearer
client_assertion="eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsIng1dCI6IjZlLzEra01scHhuTHArZFJ4d1BqS21EdmZCQT0ifQ.eyJhdWQiOiJodHRwczovL2xvZ2luLndpbmRvd3MubmV0L2ZmNjQxNTFmLTIwM2EtNGM0MC1hZDcxLTExOTE2YjY2Yzg3My9vYXV0aDIvdG9rZW4iLCJleHAiOjE0MzEwMDYzMDMsImlzcyI6ImFkMTkzY2I1LWU2NmUtNDdmNS1iMTc4LTQxM2NlODA3ZDg2YiIsImp0aSI6IjMyMDZiYWI5LTVmYmUtNDA3ZS02OWY2LTJlNGRjNDQ3NzQxYSIsIm5iZiI6MTQzMTAxMTMwMywic3ViIjoiYWQxOTNjYjUtZTY2ZS00N2Y1LWIxNzgtNDEzY2U4MDdkODZiIn0.eEOlhsl-vbdzIiV3AfGFOH187Yb8zpGSGm6RbMhDX4NRJbwOWjJr3eFK3rGXSkl1vhSfJ_oFc69pB1AGfUK8u_SWRl7U3GgH3EJryE-FiVluCQ-ONZ3Qj1u6VggXgTodi0bdvhQF4WlwazXmJGbpeVRUZBm2rlTcd8JtQY96sOu1CRDpZJOFnHzjqleVdrnw8_pNVUafwlnaosRT9tOIgiK9apjN_KY5JMM1QTYKhKk5ZApjmr8agTZpObdz-_Y9znjaSxQcYkFnQeCGc-qwISzH1OqG_7JbCDq6Dp1-oBU5sJneJaF6IxX8-sWyaju3ntMWQyINeuHnRCoPrlp2tg"
```

this is the assertion i create

```
token.Header["alg"] = "RS256"
    token.Header["x5t"] = "thumbprint of certificate "
    token.Claims["aud"] = "https://login.windows.net/" + TenantId + "/oauth2/token"
    token.Claims["exp"] = time.Now().Add(time.Hour * 72).Unix()
    token.Claims["iss"] = client_id
    token.Claims["jti"] = some guid 
    token.Claims["nbf"] = (time.Now().Add(time.Hour * 72).Unix()) + 5000
    token.Claims["sub"] = client_id
```

please let me what to be done so that i can get the access token for other organiztion's domain .
Thanks in advance

Comment: Just to be sure, the tenant ID you use for the request is the same as the tenant ID you use to build the aud parameter in the assertion, correct? And it is the tenant ID of the admin that is logging in to consent, not your tenant ID?